# RecycleView update list items while dragging

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to update the `RecycleView` list items while dragging an element, `notifyDataSetChanged()` resets the drag position. The list items in my case are updated very frequently (for example showing sensor real time data).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `notifyItemChanged()` instead `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
for (i in 0..itemCount) {
    notifyItemChanged(i)
}
```